# Can not create wait dialog while connecting

Tags: delphi

From two days I try to create simple wait dialog box, that will be shown whlie TADOConnection connect. My problem is that I need to have animated TImage (gif picture) inside the wait dialog. But while MainForm.ADOConnection connecting everything freazes (the gif also). Do someone know sample way to create dialog in separated thread before connecting, and free it after connection done?

Comment: Put the db code in the other thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your database code is going to block the thread it runs on then it stands to reason that you should not run it on a GUI thread. If you do then you'll block the GUI thread.

The logical conclusion therefore is that it is the database code that needs to run on a different thread.